# .php file changed to UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8

I changed some of my files in norepad to UTF-8 and than firefox was displaying very strange chars. I have cyryllic chars in the .php file and if iam not saving the file with UTF-8 than i get '?????'

But the issue that Iam having now is with firefox displaying stange Chars. Can anyone help me out?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure that your webserver is actually setting the charset to UTF-8. You can check this with your browser developer tools.
Some things to check:

in php.ini:

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

php code to set header:

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8');
```

Comment: Can you give us a link to the website and/or some of the code? Is the data all from a PHP file or do you pull it from a database?